# Magento rewrite headaches

Tags: magento

Just need a bit of advice. i have just finish building a site, i have turned on the Web Server Rewrites in the backend to get rid of the index.php

But when i go to the frontend it keeps giving me 404 errors

I cant seem to figure it out ... Is there anything else i need to do?

Cheers

Comment: What kind of web-server do you use? Is it apache? If not, you need to configure rewrite rules within its config file.

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod rewrite logging , regenerate your indexes

Comment: Thanks for your response ... how do i enable mod rewrite logging? ... and 'regenerate your indexes' ... Does this mean i should go to Index Management and ReIndex Data? ... i have tried the last bit

Answer (score 0):

You might have forgotten to copy the .htaccess file which is hidden on some operating systems to your magento Folder. This can easily happen on Windows or Mac OS X since they don't select hidden files when you mark all and copy from inside a directory. But they will copy hidden files when you copy whole directories, which may well explain why the issue doesn't creep up in the admin side of things.